# How can I find these addresses?

Tags: networking, ipv4, subnet

In class B subnet, we know the IP addressof one of the host and mask is give below.                                                        IP address - 182.44.82.16                            subnet mask - 255.255.255.192                  what is the first address of subnet, last address of subnet and how many address in total in between?

Comment: Network classes are dead, killed in 1993, by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which define CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking does not use network classes. Please let them rest in peace. See the excellent answer to [this question](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/7106/8499) for how to do what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

Bluntly taken from http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=182.44.82.16&mask1=26&mask2=255.255.255.192:

```
Address:   182.44.82.16          10110110.00101100.01010010.00 010000
Netmask:   255.255.255.192 = 26  11111111.11111111.11111111.11 000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.63              00000000.00000000.00000000.00 111111
=>
Network:   182.44.82.0/26        10110110.00101100.01010010.00 000000 (Class B)
Broadcast: 182.44.82.63          10110110.00101100.01010010.00 111111
HostMin:   182.44.82.1           10110110.00101100.01010010.00 000001
HostMax:   182.44.82.62          10110110.00101100.01010010.00 111110
Hosts/Net: 62
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ipcalc`](http://jodies.de/ipcalc) on Linux:

```
# ipcalc 182.44.82.16 255.255.255.192
Address:   182.44.82.16         10110110.00101100.01010010.00 010000
Netmask:   255.255.255.192 = 26 11111111.11111111.11111111.11 000000
Wildcard:  0.0.0.63             00000000.00000000.00000000.00 111111
=>
Network:   182.44.82.0/26       10110110.00101100.01010010.00 000000
HostMin:   182.44.82.1          10110110.00101100.01010010.00 000001
HostMax:   182.44.82.62         10110110.00101100.01010010.00 111110
Broadcast: 182.44.82.63         10110110.00101100.01010010.00 111111
Hosts/Net: 62                    Class B
```

Comment: Thank you so much!